# Nom, Prénom, Postnoms relative to US First, Middle, Last name

Tags: usage

Trying to clear up VISA mistake by US Embassy Kinshasa DRC on Congolese citizen applying for US Green Card. Please explain French (in DRC use) Nom, Prénom, Postnom relative to US First, Middle, Last name for official documents.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo_naming_customs). It seems that a Congolese *postnom* (*post-surname* in English)  is a thing that doesn't exist in standard US or French usage.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better on [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com)? They have a 'visas' tag and the problem here doesn't seem to be about understanding some specific French Congolese denominations but how to properly fit in those terms on a US document.

Comment: *Porter un ou plusieurs postnoms ne facilite pas toujours les choses, surtout lorsqu’il faut remplir un document officiel non congolais, comme le souligne l’enseignant Hubert Shimba.*: https://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/1522957/postnom-nom-prenom-zaire-congo-kongo-mobutu-authenticite

Comment: I’m voting to close this question it is not asking about French but about how to fill in a form on a US official document. It could be asked on [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @None I’m not sure that is the correct way of reading the question. It asks specifically about “French (in DRC use)”, and when it adds “relative to US First, Middle, Last name for official documents” that would seem to be about how Congolese names *should* be interpreted, not about how they are interpreted by authorities in the USA. (But, again, I may be wrong.)

Comment: @Segorian A question can also be closed because it "Needs details or clarity".

Comment: @None Yes; I agree on that point.

Answer (score 2):

The use of what are called in French *postnoms* is a Bantu tradition that was made mandatory in Congo-Kinshasa (then Zaïre) during the reign of Mobutu Sese Seko as a part of his efforts to do away with European traditions, including Western-style given names (“Christian names”). Mobutu himself dropped his first name Joseph-Désiré, replacing it with the *postnom(s)* Sese Seko Kuku Ngbendu wa za Banga.

After Mobutu’s departure from power, the country's naming rules were relaxed, and a practice has now developed whereby people usually have a name made up of:

- A *nom*, which nowadays tends to be a family name, but can also be a name particular to the bearer;
- One or, quite often, several *postnoms*, as a rule honouring the person’s origins (by indicating their ethnic group, birth place, or even using the name of a particular ancestor) and/or suggesting a specific character trait or some kind of connection to the natural environment;
- A *prénom*, usually short, and often French in origin.

Given that a person’s full name can be very long, most people use shortened versions of their names, most commonly a combination of either the *prénom* and the *nom*, or the *nom* and one of the *postnoms*. An example of the former is Félix Tshisekedi, the current president, whose full name is Félix Antoine Tshisekedi Tshilombo. An example of the latter is the basketball player Dikembe Mutombo, whose full name is Dikembe Mutombo Mpolondo Mukamba Jean-Jacques wa Mutombo (the *prénom* in this case being listed second-to-last).

The choice between these two options is a matter of personal preference and partly reflects a decision as to whether the most appropriate order of the different name elements is the traditional (and now official) one or the Western-style one.

On official documents, the order of the names is given as *nom-postnom-prénom*, as in the voter ID shown below. Outside Congo-Kinshasa, the *nom* is best interpreted as ‘surname’, and the *postnom/prénom* combination as ‘first name(s)’. None of them should be treated as ‘middle name’.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and moreover conflicts both with what the [Ambassade des États-Unis, Kinshasa](https://www.facebook.com/ambassadeusakinshasa/posts/des-questions-sur-le-programme-diversityvisa-nos-coll%C3%A8gues-de-la-section-consula/10157808674142090/?locale=fr_FR) answers: "Nom = last name; postnom = middle name, prenom = first name" and the [US Homeland Security](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/sevis-help-hub/sevis-basics/system-data-entry-standards/name-standards) has on their website: "The Postnom on a Congolese passport is a middle name".

Comment: @None I may be wrong, but I assumed that the “mistake” mentioned in the question was a consequence precisely of adhering to such guidelines. The problem is that no element of a Congolese name corresponds exactly (or even approximately) to the American ”middle name”, and I believe it is therefore better to treat both the *postnom* and the *prénom* as first names. If the US authorities insist on doing it differently, I don’t think there are many ways around that, but in my opinion such a policy reflects a certain amount of disrespect for Congolese traditions.